# NSDateFormatter zeroing minutes

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When converting a date string for the server into a NSDate - which is in this format

```
2012-09-07T11:57:44+10:00
```

we're using this dateFormat in NSDateFormatter

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ':'mm
```

but the minutes are always zero minutes.

Comment: That's because the second "mm" is assigning zero to minutes.

Comment: (You cannot parse that form of timestamp without first somehow removing the last `:` in the timestamp.)

Comment: @HotLicks makes complete sense. Make it an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second "mm" overwrites the result of the first and sets minutes to zero, having parsed the "00" on the end of the timezone.

In order to parse that format of timestamp you must first somehow remove the last `:` character, as NSDateFormater cannot handle that.